# Redux + Typescript + funtional component: imported component requires props that come from Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component that looks something like this:

- it has an interface with "alerts" property
- it is connected to Redux and gets "alerts" from props.

```js
interface IAlert {
  alerts: { id: string; type: string; msg: string }[];
}

const Alert: FC<IAlert> = ({ alerts }) => {
  return (
    //does something with alerts
  );
};

Alert.propTypes = {
  alerts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any): object => ({
  alerts: state.alerts
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Alert);
```

The Problem is:
When I import this component (that creates the Alerts) into another components I get this:

```
Property 'alerts' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Pick<IAlert, "alerts">'.ts(2741)
```

I don't want to pass "alerts" into the imported elemnt but just get it from Redux.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to get typescript support by using the `useSelector` hook like in @Jannis's answer.

You *can* get proper typing with `connect`.  The reason that you aren't getting it here is because the types of your `mapStateToProps` function are incorrect.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any): object => ({
  alerts: state.alerts
});
```

`connect` makes it so that the connected version of the component no longer requires the props which are added by `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps`.  *But what props are those?*.  The type definition for your `mapStateToProps` doesn't say that it returns a prop `alerts`.  It just returns `object`.

Returning `IAlert` makes your error go away because now `connect` knows that the `alerts` prop has already been provided.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any): IAlert => ({
  alerts: state.alerts
});
```

---

If you have a proper type for your `state` instead of `any` then you shouldn't need any return type at all.  For this particular component, your `IAlert` props type actually describes both the required state and the return.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IAlert) => ({
  alerts: state.alerts
});
```

But generally you want to get the state type from your store or reducer [as described here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type).

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

---

You'll need to use that `RootState` in `useSelector`, but there's a helpful shortcut so that don't need to assign the type every time that you use it.  You can create your own typed version of the `useSelector` hook [as explained here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks).

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

So now your component doesn't need any props, and the type of the `alerts` variable is known based on the type of the state

```
export default () => {

  const alerts = useAppSelector(state => state.alerts);

  return (
    //does something with alerts
  );
};
```